# Joined object won't move with the rig

Tags: rigging

I joined these teeth with my character and yet they won't move with my rig.  Everything else I joined moves with the rig.  I joined the teeth later on though so maybe that's the problem.  Does anyone know how I can get these teeth to move with my rig?

[image]

Comment: Did you originally parent the teeth to a bone? That would mean they don't have vertex group values. You can select the teeth in edit mode and assign them to a vertex group that matches the mouth bone name.

Comment: I did not do that...  Since I joined them to the character (ctrl+j) do I need to "unjoin" them now to parent them?  If so how do I separate them?